# How to control a specific attribute of DOM created using ng-repeat in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, attributes, angularjs-ng-repeat

Question:
Is there a proper way of changing the value of an attribute of dom from on to off without doing it in the controller and how can i change it because my code below change all the state even though I only clicked one element?

JSON:

```
sections = {"data": [{
    "label": "somelabel 1",
},{
    "label": "somelabel 2",
}]};
```

HTML:

```
<ul ng-repeat="data in sections.data">
    <a href="" ng-click="do_this ()" data-state="{{! state }}" >{{! data.label }}</a>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
var module = angular.module('sidebar_module', []);
module.controller('Menu2Ctrl', ['$scope',
     $scope.state = 'off';
     $scope.do_this = function(){
         if ($scope.state == 'off') {
             dosomething();
             $scope.state = 'on';
         } else {
             dosomething();
             $scope.state = 'on';
         }
     }
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way is to have all your javascript in JS files, which essentially means controllers, services etc. Not in HTML.

You have one $scope.state variable, and use that to be display the status of all sections. So the result you get is what exactly you wrote in your program :).

If you want each section to maintain their states separately,  you can include the state property in sections object as follows,

```
sections = {"data": [{
    "label": "somelabel 1", state:'on'
},{
    "label": "somelabel 2", state:'off'
}]};
```

In the do_this(), take the $index and set the state of the section,

```
$scope.do_this = function(index){
         var section = sections.data[index];
         if (section.state == 'off') {
             dosomething();
             section.state = 'on';
         } else {
             dosomethingElse();
             section.state = 'on';
         }
     }
```

In your html you will need to pass the index for do_this

```
<a href="" ng-click="do_this($index)" data-state="{{!state}}" >{{!data.label}}</a>
```

Info on [ngRepeat and $index](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Comment: My json comes directly from a webserver and i dont want to put any more data to it. I read in some documentation that it is not a good practice to change an attribute in the controller. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Once you receive the data, then you can iterate the data.section, and add the state attr for each element OR you can use a separate array for storing state for each section. As far as I know, it's standard to manipulate such attrs. However, if you need to access the states from other controllers, you may wanna have them in a ng service.

Comment: How did you go with fixing your problem. If you found my answer is correct and helpful could please mark this as the answer as explained here meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235